# Using generating function to proof E(X-Y)=E(X)-E(Y)

Tags: probability, expected-value

I recently learned about generating function (in probability), and that they are very useful. For example one can proof by using them, that E[X-Y]=E[X]-E[Y].
So as an exercise I tried it myself, but I don't understand which generating function I should use (the generating function of what?). I hope someone could explain this to me, thanks :D

Comment: The idea is to use the definition of the moment generating function - although this property follows immediately from the sum or integral definition of expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to find the generating function of $X-Y$ we need more details about the joint density which is missing i will give a proof using independency.

$G_{X-Y}(z)=E(z^{X-Y})=E(z^{X})E(z^{-Y})=G_{X}(z)G_{Y}(1/z)$

$E(X-Y)=G'_{X-Y}(1)=G'_{X}(1)G_{Y}(1/1)-G_{X}(1)G'_{Y}(1/1)=G'_{X}(1)-G'_{Y}(1)=E(X)-E(Y)$

Answer (score 2):

If I understand clearly your question, we want to prove that $E(X-Y)+E(Y)=E(X)$. We have that :

$$E(X-Y)+E(Y)=\int_\Omega (X-Y)(x)d\mathbb{P}(x)+ \int_\Omega Y(x)d\mathbb{P}(x)= \int_\Omega ((X-Y)+Y)(x)d\mathbb{P}(x) 
= \int_\Omega X(x)d\mathbb{P}(x)=E(X)$$

It is just an application of measure theory lemmas.